# Difference between Series.map and Series.apply

Tags: python, pandas

I understand the usage of [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for a `pd.Series` and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for a `pd.DataFrame`, but what is the difference between using `map` and `apply` for a `pd.Series` ? It seems to me that they essentially do the same thing:

```
>>> df['title'].map(  lambda value: str(value) + 'x')
>>> df['title'].apply(lambda value: str(value) + 'x')
```

It seems both just send a value to a function/map. Is there an actual difference between the two, and if so what would be an example showing it? Or, are these interchangeable when applied to `pd.Series` ?

---

For reference, from the docs:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

For the examples `map` uses a `dict` and `apply` uses a `func`, but really, they seem the same? Both can use a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *See also* paragraph of `Series.map` says that `Series.apply` is *For applying more complex functions on a Series.*

`Series.map` if for a one to one relation, that can be represented by a dictionary or a function of one parameter returning one value.

`Series.apply` can use functions returning more than one single parameter (in fact a whole `Series`). In that case, the result of `Series.apply` will be a `DataFrame`.

Said differently you can always use `apply` where you use `map`. If you pass a dict (say `d`) to `map`, you can pass a trivial lambda to apply: `lambda x: d[x]`. But if you use `apply` to transform a `Series` into a `DataFrame`, then `map` cannot be used.

As a result, `map` is likely to be more optimized that apply for one to one transformation, and should be used instead of `apply` wherever possible.

Comment: Also , index can only use map not apply